# Swift's Vision framework not recognizing Japanese characters

Tags: ios, swift, vision, visionkit

I would like to read Japanese characters from a scanned image using swift's Vision framework. However, when I attempt to set the recognition language of `VNRecognizeTextRequest` to Japanese using

`request.recognitionLanguages = ["ja", "en"]`

the output of my program becomes nonsensical roman letters. For each [image of japanese text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joTPE.jpg) there is [unexpected recognized text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxvmU.jpg) output. However, when set to other languages such as Chinese or German the text output is as expected. What could be causing the unexpected output seemingly peculiar to Japanese?

I am building from the github project [here](https://github.com/appcoda/TextScanner/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As they said in WWDC 2019 video, [Text Recognition in Vision Framework](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/234/?time=1161):

> First, a prerequisite, you need to check the languages that are supported by language-based correction...

Look at [`supportedRecognitionLanguages`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrecognizetextrequest/3751006-supportedrecognitionlanguages) for `VNRecognizeTextRequestRevision2` for “accurate” recognition, and it would appear that the supported languages are:

```
["en-US", "fr-FR", "it-IT", "de-DE", "es-ES", "pt-BR", "zh-Hans", "zh-Hant"]
```

If you use “fast” recognition, the list is shorter:

```
["en-US", "fr-FR", "it-IT", "de-DE", "es-ES", "pt-BR"]
```

And if you fall back to `VNRecognizeTextRequestRevision1`, it is even shorter (lol):

```
["en-US"]
```

It would appear that Japanese is not a supported language at this point.

Comment: As of March 2023 (accurate): `["en-US", "fr-FR", "it-IT", "de-DE", "es-ES", "pt-BR", "zh-Hans", "zh-Hant", "yue-Hans", "yue-Hant", "ko-KR", "ja-JP", "ru-RU", "uk-UA"]`

Answer (score 0):

VisionKit has been support more language after mac update to macos Ventura.

> need rebuild app using xcode 14

```swift
VNRecognizeTextRequest().supportedRecognitionLanguages()

["en-US", "fr-FR", "it-IT", "de-DE", "es-ES", "pt-BR", "zh-Hans", "zh-Hant", "yue-Hans", "yue-Hant", "ko-KR", "ja-JP", "ru-RU", "uk-UA"]
```